# How to use new docker image instead of old one?

Tags: docker

I have Docker version 20.10.8, build 3967b7d
installed in system.

I have pulled an new image for php version 8
currently using image that has php version 7.

I have pulled it & i can see the image in "sudo docker images"
but i am not sure how to use that image further.

Any thoughts on this ?

Comment: Any thoughts on this ?

Comment: What do you want to do with it? You could just run it, e.g. `docker run php:8.1.0RC3-zts-buster`. Or check out the [description](https://hub.docker.com/_/php?tab=description&page=1&ordering=last_updated&name=8.1) (chapter "How to use this image")

Answer (score 0):

When you start/run a container you can reference any image (also the older one) by tag if there is one available:

Example: {{imagen-name}}:{{tag-name}} => php:7.4

By running the cmd `docker images` you can see if there is a tag available. When no tag is available you can reference the image also by the image id, which is another information on this list of local images.